# How to know if a system or library call may cause my thread to be suspended?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, libc

I am wondering if there is somewhere a list of all the system and library calls that may cause the calling thread to be suspended (putted in a wait queue) ?

Note: `man` pages are not always explicit about this, see for example [man 2 read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

Comment: Any syscall or libc call can get interrupted and the calling process can be moved to wait queue for several reasons: time slice expired, resources (I/O) being unavailable. If you are more interested in what is causing the process to be moved into the wait queue, it best to look into the scheduling aspects of the process.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am working under ROUND_ROBIN real time priority and my question mainly concerns I/O not available.

Comment: What syscalls are you getting stuck on ? Have you checked the strace output, iostat, sar reports for any error codes, bottle necks ?